# Splitting numeric row data into new columns by text header

Tags: r

I have a question about data manipulation in R. A ".csv" file I am trying to analyze contains 2 columns, but multiple types of data within each column. The types of data are separated by a paragraph break. such as below.

```
"A","B"
1,2
3,4

"C","D"
5,6
7,8

"E","F"
9,10
11,12
```

I would like to transform the data so that each data set becomes a column. For example I would like the above to be transformed to:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F"
1,2,5,6,9,10
3,4,7,8,11,12
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the text by `\n\n` and then use `read.csv` and then `cbind` result together

```
txt <- '"A","B"
1,2
3,4

"C","D"
5,6
7,8

"E","F"
9,10
11,12'

do.call(cbind, lapply(unlist(strsplit(txt, split='\n\n')), function(x) read.csv(text=x)))

##  A B C D  E  F
##  1 1 2 5 6  9 10
##  2 3 4 7 8 11 12
```

Additionally, if you have to read the content from the file as 1 string, you can do it using

```
txt <- readChar('temp.txt', nchars=file.info('temp.txt')$size)
txt
##  [1] "\"A\",\"B\"\r\n1,2\r\n3,4\r\n\r\n\"C\",\"D\"\r\n5,6\r\n7,8\r\n\r\n\"E\",\"F\"\r\n9,10\r\n11,12"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recycling to choose 1,4,7 lines...Then 2,5,8 lines , etc,...
For example :

```
  (1:9)[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)]
[1] 1 4 7
> (1:9)[c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)]
[1] 2 5 8
> (1:9)[c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)]
[1] 3 6 9
```

Using your data you can do:

```
dat <- read.table(text='"A","B"
1,2
3,4

"C","D"
5,6
7,8

"E","F"
9,10
11,12',sep=',')


 rbind(
  as.character(unlist(dat[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),])),
unlist(dat[c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),]),
unlist(dat[c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),]))


    V11 V12 V13 V21  V22  V23 
[1,] "A" "C" "E" "B"  "D"  "F" 
[2,] "1" "4" "6" "12" "14" "10"
[3,] "3" "5" "2" "13" "15" "11"
```